# How do I get Android Virtual Machine on an older computer?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I have an older computer(cpu: AMD Phenom X4 955, gpu: RTX 2060, 8gb ram), and i have problems using the Android Virtual Device, it shows a black screen and thats all, is there any way to get it working on my machine without upgrading my cpu, I use Linux as my primary OS so preferably on Linux. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a smartphone? Because you can upload the SDK on your smartphone, and teste on it.

Answer (score 1):

You may find that performance is really slow if you try using both Android Studio and the emulator at the same time on an 8GB machine.

In terms of your graphics output, I recommend:

- Choosing a lower resolution, such as 1280x720
- Playing with the various options in the "Emulated Performance" section of the AVD Manager, as you may have better luck specifying either "Hardware" or "Software"

[image: AVD Manager]

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problem with the Device Emulator you could try using a smartphone the Android studio can install in the smartphone the application.
But if you are having problem with the Android Studio, because it's to heavy, you can download others old versions in this site:

https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

However there is some limitations like:
Not being able to use the latest versions of Android, or maybe new tools.